# Vue keep-alive label not working when setting the keepAlive true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have three routes in my project, dashboard dashboard_detail and app_score.

I want to keep my data not refreshing again when I return to dashboard through detail page.

```
<keep-alive v-if="$route.meta.keepAlive">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </keep-alive>
        <router-view v-if="!$route.meta.keepAlive"></router-view>
```

I had set a variable called 'keepAlive' in the meta label in route>index.js.
[image]

[image]
But the problem is it always refresh when returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<keep-alive>
        <router-view v-if="$route.meta.keepAlive"></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view v-if="!$route.meta.keepAlive"></router-view>
```